# How to remove white space in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

[image: Datagrid in Wpf]

In this picture I had used Data grid with `AutogeneratedColumn=false`

Now how do I remove the white space in this Datagrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set fill width (`*`) for the last column:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <!-- The number of columns -->
    <!-- The last column -->
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Note, that if you want to share space fill between several columns, you have to set relative fill width:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <!-- The number of columns -->
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="40*"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="20*"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```